# An operator that is normal but not self-adjoint

Tags: linear-algebra, self-adjoint-operators, normal-operator

I am trying to find the example of an operator an operator $T\in L(V)$ where $V=C^{2}$.

Could this be an example?

Let $(e_{1},e_{2})$ be an orthonormal basis of $C^{2}$, an operator $T\in L(C^{2})$ such that $T(e_{1})=e_{1}$ and $T(e_{2})=ie_{2}$.

If not, can someone give me an example?

Comment: Have you checked the definition?

Answer (score 2):

Your example seems to work.  Recall that a linear map is normal if $TT^* = T^*T$.  The matrix representation for the mapping you've defined is

$$
T \;\; =\;\; \left [ \begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 \\
0 & i \\
\end{array} \right ]
$$

We can clearly compute that $TT^* = T^*T = I$, but

$$
T^* \;\; =\;\; \left [ \begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 \\
0 & -i \\
\end{array} \right ] \;\; \neq \;\; T.
$$